# Scraping values from "data-" with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have stuff like this:

```
<div class="new-faceout p13nimp" id="purchase_B005ZVWBGK" data-asin="B005ZVWBGK" data-ref="pd_sim_hg_1">
```

I'm scraping its data like this:

```
 product_product = @data.css('#purchaseShvl')

    product_product.css('.shoveler-cell').each do | product_product |
      product_product_asin  = product_product.xpath('.//div[@class="new-faceout"]')
```

(etc...)

How can I extract the values of `data-asin` and `data-ref`?

I tried this:

```
 product_product_asin  = product_product.xpath('.//div[@class="new-faceout"]/@data-ref').first.value
```

but the value returns `nil`.

Live page: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BATSB60/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BATSB60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#attr`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-attr) method to get attribute:

```
>> prd = product_product.at_css('.new-faceout')

>> prd.attr('data-asin')
=> "B005ZVWBGK"
>> prd.attr('data-ref')
=> "pd_sim_hg_1"
```

You can also use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
>> prd['data-asin']
=> "B005ZVWBGK"
>> prd['data-ref']
=> "pd_sim_hg_1"
```

Comment: why this `product_product.css('.new-faceout')[0]` ?

Comment: Humm That's my intention to tell you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying HTML classes with XPath is a bit tricky. In this case you can’t just use `[@class="new-faceout"]` because the actual value of the `class` attribute is `new-faceout p13nimp` so it doesn’t match. You would need to use something like this:

```
[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' new-faceout ')]
```

as the condition. There are quite a few questions here on Stack Overflow about this, as well as elsewhere on the web.

With Nokogiri you can combine css and XPath to produce a simpler technique, by fetching the node with CSS first, and then using XPath, e.g.

```
@data.at_css('.new-faceout').at_xpath('./@data-ref')
```

Or if you have fetched the node with CSS you can use the Nokogiri methods `attribute` (or `attr` or just `[]` to fetch the attribute value directly:

```
@data.at_css('.new-faceout')['data-ref']
```

Comment: Why we need `concat(' ', @class, ' ')` at all?

Comment: @Babai, to prevent match attribute value like `new-faceout-wrapper` unlike `contains(@class,'new-faceout')`.

Comment: @falsetru Please stop guessing..Always good to answer as per the information available,which will help future readers..for me not worthful...there could be many things,we shouldn't guess one out of them.. Its good to answer as per the question..

Comment: @Babai, [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/css/xpath_visitor.rb#L123) also uses a similar expression.

Comment: @falsetru thanks frnd.. I understood.. and change the same to my answer too.. thanks for prompt reply..